# sort database by 2 fields

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to query a database with a sorted order by the name of an item and date of an item.

for example first I want to get all the names of the items in alphabetical order and thats no problem but there can be multiple items with the same name so I also want to sort them by the date that I insert them into the database like this

A 1/1/12,
A 1/2/12,
A 1/3/12,
B 1/1/12,
B 1/2/12,
B 1/3/12,
etc....

how can I do this?

All the sorting I have done was by just one field like this

```
CalendarEvents.EVENT_START + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC"
```

this is the database I want to sort

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + EMGNOTE_TABLE + "(" + EMG_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                EMG_NOTE_ID + " INTEGER, " + EMG_CDID + " INTEGER, " + EMG_CENTER_POINT + " TEXT, " + EMG_COMPANY_NAME +
                " TEXT, " + EMG_NAME + " TEXT, " + EMG_DESC + " TEXT, " + EMG_START_DATE + " TEXT, " + EMG_TTL + " TEXT, "
                + EMG_CENTER_LAT + " TEXT, " + EMG_CENTER_LON + " TEXT, " + EMG_LOCATION_TYPE + " TEXT, " + EMG_UPDATED + " TEXT, " + EMG_READ + " INTEGER);");
```

the field `EMG_START_DATE` would be the date i want to sort by

sort now looks like this

```
CursorLoader(getActivity(),CalendarEvents.EVENTS_URI,
new String[] {CalendarEvents.EVENT_ID,CalendarEvents.EVENT_READ,CalendarEvents.EVENT_SUBJECT,
CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME,CalendarEvents.EVENT_START}
,null
,null
,CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC, julianday("+CalendarEvents.EVENT_START + ")" + "COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't showed your DB schema so I will assume you have an `ITEM_NAME` column and an `ITEM_DATE` columns stored as `TEXT` in ISO8601 format.
In that case you have to simply use this `orderBy` in your query:

```
"ITEM_NAME ASC, julianday(ITEM_DATE)"
```

### Update

According to the schema, it should be (I guess):

```
"INCIDENT_STATON_NAME ASC, juliandate(INCIDENT_TOC)"
```

Comment: Updated question with database schema

Comment: I am still having a problem getting the date to order correctly now though, they do not appear in any order. the date I store is sent from a server in format `1/1/12 12:00:00PM`

Comment: store dates in ISO8601 format, perhaps you have to modify them while you are inserting

Comment: if you convert while you insert you have to do it once, otherwise if you create a method of obtaining the right ordering in the SELECT statement you'll have to do it every time